# Tensorflow ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python

The Error it gives me is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\intel\Desktop\Python Projects\Pong\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tens
orflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\intel\Desktop\Python Projects\Pong\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tens
orflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\intel\Desktop\Python Projects\Pong\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tens
orflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\intel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\intel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AI.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\intel\Desktop\Python Projects\Pong\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101,
 in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\intel\Desktop\Python Projects\Pong\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line
 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\intel\Desktop\Python Projects\Pong\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50,
in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\intel\Desktop\Python Projects\Pong\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44,
in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\intel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in imp
ort_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\intel\Desktop\Python Projects\Pong\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py
", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\intel\Desktop\Python Projects\Pong\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tens
orflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\intel\Desktop\Python Projects\Pong\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tens
orflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\intel\Desktop\Python Projects\Pong\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tens
orflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\intel\Desktop\Python Projects\Pong\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tens
orflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\intel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\intel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I tried Force reinstalling tensorflow gpu but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

The ImportError message is a bit misleading because of the reference to Win32, whereas the problem was simply the opencv DLLs were not found.

This problem was solved by adding the OpenCV binaries to the Windows PATH environment variable (opencv binaries path, eg ” C:\opencv\build\bin\Release” ) by following steps:

Control panel -> System and security -> System -> Advanced system settings->  Environment Variables

You could click New button to add it.

Then restart the machine.